# Increase cell size for Bokeh figure in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

the output from a `bokeh.models gridplot` combined figure is larger than the maximum cell size in Visual Studio Code's Python Interactive window. I use 3 figures and put them together in a column. Unfortunately that means a lot of scrolling in the interactive window, because the resulting figure is of course about 3 times the size of the single figures. When doing the same thing in Jupyter in the browser, the figure is displayed normally.

I can not simply increase `plot_height`, because that increases each figure's individual size. I was hoping for a maximum-size parameter in VSC, but I could not find any.

Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Also for vscode 1.63 please :)

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else who comes upon this, in File -> Preferences -> Settings. Under User settings, under Extensions, under Python, way down in the Data Science options there is a setting for "Max Output Size" which controls the cell height before a scroll bar appears.

Or faster, open Settings and type "Max Output Size" into the search bar.

I'm using VS Code 1.45.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems to be working in Windows 10 as well (VSC 1.46.0).

Answer (score 3):

[image: CHange the Max Output Size]
open Settings and type "Max Output Size" into the search bar.

Comment: 1.63.0 is missing this option :-(

Comment: Also for me this options is missing in 1.63, if anyone can help?